# Fitting a non-normal ARMA process: OLS or MLE?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, least-squares, normality-assumption, arma

If I want to fit an ARMA on data whose white noise part is non-normal is it better to estimate the model with OLS or with MLE? In other words, is OLS or MLE better for non-normal white noise in time series?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Distribution of White Noise in Time Series](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164529/distribution-of-white-noise-in-time-series)

Comment: Why don't you post your data as there are a number of reasons why what you assert may be true. There are possible remedies BUT only the data will tell what they might be for your case.

Comment: I don't see an answer in the linked thread that explains whether OLS or MLE is better for non-normal noise in time series. It doesn't quite seem like a duplicate to me.

Comment: Thanks @gung you rephrase my question very well, I added it to the text.

Comment: What is your likelihood function that you are going to use MLE with?  MLE is never less efficient, but it may be  bear to compute.

Comment: This is a theoretical question so I have note data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## ARMA($p,q$) with $q>0$

ARMA($p,q$) model cannot be estimated by OLS if $q>0$, because the design matrix cannot be constructed (it includes lagged errors which are unobservable). However, MLE or conditional MLE are feasible options.

## ARMA($p,q$) with $q=0$

When $q=0$, both OLS and (conditional or unconditional) MLE are feasible.
OLS estimation will be equivalent to conditional MLE with the assumption that the errors are normally distributed.

For nonnormal error distributions, OLS will be consistent, and

- if the error distribution is correctly specified, MLE will be more efficient than OLS (however, specifying a correct error distribution might not be easy);
- if the error distribution is misspecified, MLE might be inconsistent.

## Summary

- If $q>0$, forget OLS.
- If $q=0$, OLS is a relatively safe choice due to consistency regardless of the error distribution.
  MLE or conditional MLE could be preferred to OLS when the error distribution can be guessed with good accuracy as then MLE would be more efficient. Otherwise OLS seems safer.

Comment: If I want to fit an ARMA(p,q) through MLE how can I choose/guess the most probable error distribution?

Comment: @user142505, The common thing to do is assume normality and later interpret the estimator as quasi MLE if the realized error distribution is not quite normal. (I do not think there are too many canned routines that would fit an ARMA model with nonnormal errors, so you might need to do some independent programming if you wish to try another distribution.) I think there has been a thread on what happens to ARMA/ARIMA under nonnormality. And there has been a note in a blog post by Rob J. Hyndman. I do not remember exactly where these were, but they should be possible to find.

Comment: After some basic searching, I could not find anything on Rob J. Hyndman's blog, so maybe it is not there. But see also Mazzeu et al. ["Model uncertainty and the forecast accuracy of ARMA models: A survey"](http://orff.uc3m.es/bitstream/handle/10016/20707/ws1508.pdf?sequence=1) (2015).