# Using OLS to estimate an ARMA(1,1)

Tags: arima

Is it possible to obtain a consistent OLS estimator of an AR-parameter, given that the true process is an ARMA(1,1)? - It is purely a theoretical question regarding whether the AR-parameter is consistently estimated in the presence of moving average processes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/251805/127281.

Comment: @lucasfariaslf It is not a duplicate. Here, the OP already understand that with OLS we can only estimate the AR-parameter, and wonders whether the estimator will be consistent or not.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Got it, thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the **ARMA (1,1)** model

$$y_t = \rho y_{t-1} + v_t + \theta v_{t-1}$$

with $v_t$ white noise, the OLS estimator is

$$\hat \rho = \frac {\sum y_ty_{t-1}}{\sum y_{t-1}^2} = \rho + \frac {\sum v_ty_{t-1} +\sum \theta v_{t-1}y_{t-1}}{\sum y_{t-1}^2}$$

We have that $(1/T)\sum v_ty_{t-1} \to_p 0$, and we are left to consider

$$(1/T)\sum \theta v_{t-1}y_{t-1} = (1/T)\sum \theta v_{t-1}[\rho y_{t-2} + v_{t-1} + \theta v_{t-2}] $$

Discarding terms that go to zero in probability asymptotically

$$\text{plim}(\hat \rho-\rho) = \theta\cdot\frac { \text{plim}(1/T)\sum v^2_{t-1}}{\text{plim}(1/T)\sum y_{t-1}^2} \neq 0$$

So it is not consistent.
After a bit of calculations we have

$$\frac { \text{plim}(1/T)\sum v^2_{t-1}}{\text{plim}(1/T)\sum y_{t-1}^2} \to \frac {1-\rho^2}{1+\theta^2+2\rho \theta}$$

so

$$\text{plim}(\hat \rho-\rho) = \frac {\theta(1-\rho^2)}{1+\theta^2+2\rho \theta}$$

Comment: Alecos, shouldn't it be $$y_{t-1}^2$$ in the denominator and not $$y_{t}^2$$ But the statement of the OLS estimator to be inconsistent when estimating the AR parameter still stands I suppose?

Comment: @user162158 Yes, thank you for spotting this, corrected. The conclusion stands, since the process is stationary so unconditional moments do not depend on the index.